# Exposed App not Visible for adding in Azure App Permissions

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-app-registration

I have registered an App in Azure and exposed the App with Custom Scope.

[image]

I have registered one more app and when I am trying to add in API permissions the exposed API custom scope I am not bale to see them under My APIs.

[image]

What could be possible reasons for this?
What else things I am missing for this to work?

Comment: check in APIs my organization uses tab

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Note** that: The Expose an API custom scope will be present in **APIs my organization uses** tab.

I exposed and API in the Azure AD application:

[image]

Now to grant the API permission, ***Go to API permissions -> Add a permission -> APIs my organization uses -> Search your app***

[image]

[image]

The API permissions granted successfully:

[image]